What exactly do I buy when I buy an index-following ETF?
Say I buy 1 piece of an index-following ETF like VOO (follows SP500 AFAIK). What exactly have I bought? And what happens to it over time as the index composition changes?
My understanding is that I bought a percentage of the shares that the ETF has at this exact moment in time. E.g. 1 share of Apple and 2 shares of Microsoft. Now say that in 10 years MS has gone out of the SP500. What is that 1 piece of my ETF composed of now? Just the 1 share of Apple remaining or is it somehow rebalanced to the new composition of ETF?

You buy a share of the ETF. The ETF tracks the index. In order to do so, they buy and sell securities to keep the same return as the index.

Some mainly use derivatives to do so.
Most unleveraged equity index ETFs just buy more or less exactly what is in the index (as does VOO). For these, you usually find the data on the website. See https://investor.vanguard.com/investment-products/etfs/profile/voo.




If a stock drops out of the index, VOO sells it.
If a stock enters, Vanguard buys it.





For a broader understanding, the index level is unaffected by index rebalancing. It is true that prices and outstanding shares change during rebalancing, but the divisor will change to account for this.
(Divisor) after rebalancing =
Index market value after rebalancing/ Index value before rebalancing
Every index will show the calculations online, see for example this link for the S&P500.

Thanks. So in case of rebalancing the ETF share that I bought in the past is now a share in the rebalanced ETF, right? That way the share age is only important in the calculation of accumulated interest of it and not its value per se?

What do you mean with share age? What is accumulated interest of it? I think you overcomplicate things. You give the ETF money. They buy what's in the SPX and rebalance whenever needed. You get indirect  exposure to the stocks in the index for a small fee.

The question is simple.
I buy a share of ETF now. Call it share A.
I buy another share after 10 years. Call it share B.
Are these 2 equivalent ?

"You give the ETF money. They buy what's in the SPX" That's how mutual funds work but ETF shares are created and destroyed in a different way.  An 'approved participant' buys a bundle of stocks that match the composition of the ETF. The AP then trades that bundle for shares of the ETF and then can sell those ETF shares.

@big_in_japan Yes, they are 100% equivalent

Correct @JimmyJames, but going into details of who has the right to create and redeem shares of an ETF is in my opinion an unnecessary complication, especially if the OP thinks that the composition of his / her share may never change. I think it is sufficient to say that the ETF just rebalances in this case.

@big_in_Japan, how do you think it would be possible to have a quoted price and exchange trading for the ETF if all the shares would be different, depending on when you bought them?

It's a minor point but it may be the case that at a specific point in time when index membership is changed, an index ETF (or fund) may not match the exact composition of the index.  The reason for this is that, for example, if every S&P500 fund and ETF bought and sold the same stocks at the same moment (or even in the same session) it could cause liquidity issues which would be immensely worse if traders knew exactly when that would happen.

@JimmyJames that doesn't sound right to me. It's exactly because the traders all know when it'll happen that there aren't liquidity issues. Everyone knows that the index funds will be doing a big trade that day (generally on the closing auction), so prop firms and hedge funds prepare and compete to provide liquidity to that trade.

"Are these 2 equivalent ?" Yes; they both represent "1 /  of the value of portfolio the ETF currently holds".

@JimmyJames the fact that the ETF's investment likely do not match with the index 1:1 at all points is probably quite irrelevant for the ETF-buyer. Their shares track the index, and technically the fund could invest in something else instead. (I'm not versed in the regulations here, though).

@BenMillwood First let's be clear on what a liquidity means.  It means that an asset can be bought or sold at without moving the price significantly.  A liquid asset for you or me isn't necessarily liquid for a large fund like VOO.  If you think that it's possible to sell a significant portion of shares outstanding without moving the price, you are definitely misguided.  You really think that there's no hedge fund that would try to take advantage of a large, predictable, forced sale. If an index fund did this, they would be failing their investors.

" You really think that there's no hedge fund that would try to take advantage of a large, predictable, forced sale." -- of course there is, in fact there are many such hedge funds, and they all compete with each other to provide the best price, so that actually the index fund ends up getting a pretty reasonable deal. Most days if you trade a huge volume of stock, you're going to move the price a lot. But if you trade them when everyone knows you're going to trade them and how much you're going to trade, it's not an issue.

Much like when you buy parts of a company, you buy shares of an ETF or a mutual fund.  In the case you cite, VOO, the cost of a single share is around $500.  One may not have $500 to invest now, so some brokerages allow investors to buy
fractional shares.
So if one had about $125 they could buy .25 shares of VOO if the price was $500.
This process is somewhat simplified with buying mutual funds as you just send in the amount you have to invest.  In returned you are awarded fractional shares typically to three decimal digits.  For example you might receive 23.886 shares for a certain fund for a certain amount.
As an owner of a share you essentially have a portion of the assets of that fund that probably includes company shares and reserve cash.  So even if you have 100 shares of VOO that might represent .00000001 shares of Apple, .00000004 shares of Microsoft as well 498 other stocks and some cash.  (Numbers are not meant to be accurate only illustrative.)
Given that VOO is a indexed fund you can predict or calculate with a decent degree of certainty how much of each stock you own.  A managed fund could be different as securities are traded at the discretion of the management team.
All that being said, why is that important to you?  No one would say that they own .0004 shares of Apple because they own X shares of VOO.  Even the amount of shares you own of a fund is somewhat unimportant.  The only thing one normally tracks is the amount.  How much is my fund worth?  How much has it gone up or down in the last month/year/etc...?
Sure, you can do all the calculations and be somewhat accurate, but why waste time?  You are far better off doing activities to increase your income so you have more money to invest.
Please clarify on why this matters.

Didn't address the question of what if a stock is dropped from the index. OP wanted to know if they'd still be holding any of the example stock, or not.

@ChrisW.Rea Since an index fund investor doesn’t own any shares of a company that’s included in the index, it’s pretty obvious that they still won’t own any shares when it’s dropped from the index.

This seems to conflate ETFs with mutual funds.  But I thought their structures are different: with  an ETF you (or, more realistically, someone much bigger than you) has the right to swap units of the ETF for a bundle of shares (or bonds or whatever) in the all individual companies, in either direction, so while holding ETF units does not mean you own all the individual shares it does mean you do have a right to own all the individual shares, not something that can occur with a mutual fund. With index changes, the shape of the ETF bundle changes too.

@Henry: I've yet to hear of an ETF that allows such a thing.  It'd be a huge pain anyway given the logistics of shares of shares.  (You'd need to be able to distribute a fraction of a share to people who don't own even one of the original.) The biggest difference between ETFs and mutual funds is how and when they're bought and sold...that's about it

@cHao I think Henry is referring to the redemption and creation mechanism which is a distinct feature of ETFs that mutual funds don't have. It's this mechanism that gives ETFs tax advantages over mutual funds.

@JimmyJames: OK, that makes some sense, but also isn't something normies can do, is it?

@cHao No, you need to be an 'authorized participant': "Authorized Participants (APs) are institutional investors or market makers that are approved by the ETF issuer to create and redeem ETF shares."  Also, you need to have 50K shares of the ETF (or equivalent basket of securities) to make such a trade.

@MikeScott It may be obvious, but nonetheless that's what the question asks.

When the companies in the index change, the ETF sells its shares of the companies that were removed, and uses those proceeds to buy shares of the companies that were added.
So if you previously considered yourself to (indirectly) own shares of Microsoft, you'll no longer own those, but instead will own shares of whatever company replaced it in the index.
Because your ownership is indirect, you don't have any of the rights of a direct shareholder. You can't attend the annual meeting or vote your shares. Instead, the fund manager exercises those rights on behalf of all the fund investors.
